# Change default selection on drop down menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am using an extension called JTickets to manage payments in Jomsocial events, I would like to change a fields default selection from limited seats to unlimited seats, code is as follows:-

```
$unlimited_seats_options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', 1, JText::_('COM_JTICKETING_UNLIMITED_SEATS_YES'));
$unlimited_seats_options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', 0, JText::_('COM_JTICKETING_UNLIMITED_SEATS_NO'));


      <!--ticket_type_unlimited Seats-->
       <div class="form-group  jticketing-form-group" >
          <div class="jticketing-controls col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-3 jt-input-text">
             <div class="">
                <?php
                   if ($tickettype->unlimited_seats)
                   {
                       $avalaible_class="ticket_type_available_field_hide";

                    echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $unlimited_seats_options, "ticket_type_unlimited_seats[]", 'class="chzn-done jticket_access" onchange="togglefield(this,\'ticket_type_available_field\')" data-chosen="com_jticketing"', "value", "text", $tickettype->unlimited_seats,"ticket_type_unlimited_seats_".$j);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        $avalaible_class="";
                        echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $unlimited_seats_options, "ticket_type_unlimited_seats[]", 'class="chzn-done jticket_access" onchange="togglefield(this,\'ticket_type_available_field\')" data-chosen="com_jticketing"', "value", "text",0,"ticket_type_unlimited_seats_".$j);

                   }
                   ?>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <!--ticket_type_unlimited Seats DIV ENDS-->
```

currently drop down menu is set to limited seat, i would like to set default value to unlimited seats

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to have

`$tickettype->unlimited_seats = 1;`

or just

`echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $unlimited_seats_options, "ticket_type_unlimited_seats[]", 'class="chzn-done jticket_access" onchange="togglefield(this,\'ticket_type_available_field\')" data-chosen="com_jticketing"', "value", "text", 1,"ticket_type_unlimited_seats_".$j);`